# Angular mat-sidenav-container fullscreen scrollbar not working

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, scrollbar, fullscreen

I have a problem with my scrollbar and fullscreen attribute on mat-sidenav-container.
Here is my code (my app-root):

```
<mat-sidenav-content class="main-content">
     <mat-toolbar fxLayout="column">
        .
        .
        .
     </mat-toolbar>
     <!-- The 'overflow-y: hidden;' is here because i had 2 scrollbars-->
     <mat-sidenav-content style="overflow-y: hidden;">
        <div>
           <router-outlet>
           </router-outlet>
         </div>
     </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

In my index.html :

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

And the problem with my scrollbar is :[Not entire scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20yK5.png)

I don't have the entire scrollbar and i don't see the bottom of my page.
Do you have a solution to get a proper scrollbar with the fullscreen attribute on mat-sidenav-content.
Ty.

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz? To reproduce it and help to find a solution